# What's the difference between polymorphic and write several one-to-many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails
here are the 2 ways of making a Drummer model and Cymbal model both have many videos

1st way by using polymorphic:

```
class Drummer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :videos, :as => :videoable
end

class Cymbal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :videos, :as => :videoable
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :videoable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

2nd way by using two 1:m association:

```
class Drummer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :videos
end

class Cymbal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :videos
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :drummer
  belongs_to :cymbal
end
```

I haven't try them in console, But I think both will work as they should. But I don't know the difference?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you must use polymorphic method because a model cannot belongs_to (one to one association) more than one other model. For more info see this rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the columns you have in your database. If you have `videoable_type` and `videoable_id` you're doing polymorphism. In that case, calling `videoable` on an instance of `Video` can return anything, it's not related to drummers or cymbals. If it is `drummer_id` and `cymbal_id` it's the latter version you described.

Answer (score 0):

Both will work.

Imagine you have 5 models sharing Videos.

- You would need 5 modelName_id columns in videos.
- To determine which type of parent model you have on Video you would need to check each one for id presence.
- Validating that only one of the ids is set would be necessary (or valuable).
- Polymorphic relations are easier to maintain and expand in such cases.